# PHP sqlsrv_fetch_array with "while loop" crosses the first row

Tags: php, sql-server, loops, while-loop, sqlsrv

I get data from MScost table for input to tmp_table. 
I use while loop with sqlsrv_fetch_array to insert in to tmp_table table.
getData and addData is my function that I created for get data from my DB and add data into my DB.

```
$resm1 = getData($conn, "years,months,category,ROUND(mfg,0)as ttl", "MScost", "years='2018' and months='NOV'");

if($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($resm1, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) != Null){
    while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($resm1, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $category = $row['category'];
        $ttl = $row['ttl'];
        addData($conn, "tmp_table(category,ttl1)", "'$category','$ttl'");
    }
    echo $category."=".$ttl."</br>";
}else {
    addData($conn, "tmp_table(category,ttl1)", "'NON',0");
    echo "Null";
}
```

It's not have any error. 
But while loop crosses the first row that exists.
It's not show. It's not insert into database.

Then I tried to copy while loop paste outside IF, It's not crosses the first row. It works normally.

Why is this? I want it to work in IF without crossing the first row. How can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a look at this code:

```
if($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($resm1, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) != Null){
    while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($resm1, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
```

In `if` statement you have already called `sqlsrv_fetch_array`, which means that the first row **has been already fetched**. In your `while` loop you do more `sqlsrv_fetch_array` calls that return you next rows (after the first one).

The `if` statement itself (though it must be removed) is not correct too, you have to use brackets to compose a valid statement, use `!==` for comparison and write `null` in lower case always:

```
if (($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($resm1, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) !== null) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you read the first row from your result set with `if($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($resm1, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) != Null)` check. Remove this check and you'll be able to fetch all your data.

You may try with the following script:

```
<?php
$resm1 = getData($conn, "years,months,category,ROUND(mfg,0)as ttl", "MScost", "years='2018' and months='NOV'");

$rc = 0;
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($resm1, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
   $rc++;
   $category = $row['category'];
   $ttl = $row['ttl'];
   addData($conn, "tmp_table(category,ttl1)", "'$category','$ttl'");
   echo $category."=".$ttl."</br>";
}
if ($rc == 0) {
   addData($conn, "tmp_table(category,ttl1)", "'NON',0");
   echo "Null";
}
?>
```

PHP Driver for SQL Server supports [sqlsrv_num_rows()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/sqlsrv-num-rows?view=sql-server-2017) function, which returns the number of rows in a result set. But you must use this function only if your call to [sqlsrv_query()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/sqlsrv-query?view=sql-server-2017) uses a client-side, static, or keyset cursor(a forward cursor is the default).