# Iterating through an array in PHP while loop

Tags: php

I'm trying to save multiple images to a location as per below snippet. I'd like to name the images as per the search query (4 product codes in the example), however getting `Trying to access array offset on value of type bool` error. I think this is because the search query is throwing an array of data, I'm not sure how I adjust the while loop to iterate through each line of data to name the image dynamically.

Here's what I've tried. Much appreciate if someone can assist.

```
$sql = "SELECT 
         Picture 
        ,ParentId 
        ,P.Code as 'ProductCode'
       FROM dbo.IWS_Stock_Images img
       LEFT OUTER JOIN ic.Product P on P.ProductId=img.ParentId
       WHERE P.Code IN('GAI4030','GAI4037A', 'GAI1008', 'GAI4990')";

$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
if ($stmt === false) {
    echo "Error (sqlsrv_query): ".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
    exit;
} else {

$A = 1;

while ($row=sqlsrv_fetch($stmt)) {
     $idd = $row['ProductCode'];
     $image = sqlsrv_get_field($stmt, 0, SQLSRV_PHPTYPE_STREAM(SQLSRV_ENC_BINARY));
    file_put_contents($idd.'.jpg', $image);
    $A++;
        
 }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the manual how [sqlsrv_fetch()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-fetch.php) works? If you do, you'll see that it says: _"Returns true if the next row of a result set was successfully retrieved, false if an error occurs, and null if there are no more rows in the result set."_ so you're using it wrong. You probably want to use [sqlsrv_fetch_array()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-fetch-array.php) instead.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you are not using PHP PDO?

Comment: Related: [PHP sqlsrv_fetch_array with "while loop" crosses the first row](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54800941/2943403) and [hotexample snippet](https://hotexamples.com/examples/-/-/sqlsrv_fetch/php-sqlsrv_fetch-function-examples.html#0xf7e5b967bd1a729b91a7d0afc37c9f957d2d6b6101177eebe57766cc3b873a35-130,,160,) and [PHP retrieve multiple rows with stream content at once with sqlsrv](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68378902/2943403)

Answer (score 0):

[Per the docs for `sqlsrv_get_field`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-get-field.php), "Fields must be accessed in order. i.e. If you access field index 1, then field index 0 will not be available." You may not be able to mix and match this type of access with the array-style access you are using in the previous line. At minimum this access would need to be the first thing you do.

Comment: I had a look at the docs and you're correct. Are you able to throw me an example? My understanding is limited to avoid the mix and match I've done like you've pointed out!